# How to scrape one P tag from multiple p tags from BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

The website has multiple P tags but I just want to scrape one of the tags. Website inspection as per below:

```
<div class="sidebar sbt">
 <h4>history</h4>
   <p class="top">
        <strong>First </strong><br>
              Jun 2017
   </p>
   <p class="top">
        <strong>Page </strong><br>
        Last 30 days: <strong>200</strong>        
   </p>
   <p class="top">
        <strong>Last </strong><br>
        2019
    </p>
        </div>
```

As per the above there are numerous P tags, if I wanted to scrape just one of them e.g First Jun 2017, how would I do that with the soup.findAll(..) function?

Answer (score 2):

You can try it. Here I am using `soup.findAll(..)` function:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import requests
html_doc="""
<div class="sidebar sbt">
 <h4>history</h4>
   <p class="top">
        <strong>First </strong><br>
              Jun 2017
   </p>
   <p class="top">
        <strong>Page </strong><br>
        Last 30 days: <strong>200</strong>        
   </p>
   <p class="top">
        <strong>Last </strong><br>
        2019
    </p>
        </div>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'lxml')
result = soup.findAll('p')[0].text
print(" ".join(result.split()))
```

Output will be:

```
First Jun 2017
```

Comment: That worked for me in my case. But why did you use the split ( ) method ? is there a certain reason your using the split( ) method ? you can get the same output if you left the split method out, and delete an extra space for the blank string. Like the following print( ''. join ( result ) )

Answer (score 1):

Type soup.p and this will give you the first result from the given HTML data.

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> htmlData = '''
... <div class="sidebar sbt">
...  <h4>history</h4>
...    <p class="top">
...         <strong>First </strong><br>
...               Jun 2017
...    </p>
...    <p class="top">
...         <strong>Page </strong><br>
...         Last 30 days: <strong>200</strong>        
...    </p>
...    <p class="top">
...         <strong>Last </strong><br>
...         2019
...     </p>
...         </div>
... '''
>>>
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlData, 'html.parser')
>>> soup.p
<p class="top">
<strong>First </strong><br>
              Jun 2017
   </br></p>
>>>
```

If we want to scrape the nth data then

```
soup.select("p:nth-of-type(n)")
```

Example:

```
>>> soup.select("p:nth-of-type(3)")
[<p class="top">
<strong>Last </strong><br>
        2019
    </br></p>]
>>> soup.select("p:nth-of-type(2)")
[<p class="top">
<strong>Page </strong><br>
        Last 30 days: <strong>200</strong>
</br></p>]
>>> soup.select("p:nth-of-type(1)")
[<p class="top">
<strong>First </strong><br>
              Jun 2017
   </br></p>]
>>>
```

[More about CSS selectors](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors)

Another alternate way, you can try to find all the p tags and then iterate over it to find the desire one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.getText()` and compare with the text you want, after you have got all the `<p>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want to target `p` elements according to text. Here's one way of doing that.

The most significant line is the one that uses a regular expression to find 'Last 30 days', which is just part of the string in a `p` element. Having found this string you can find its parent and then display the entire `text` of that parent or other chunks of the parent.

Notice that since I've used `find_all` the result is a list (because there could be more than one item). I needed to choose the first, element zero.

```
>>> import bs4
>>> HTML = open('temp.htm').read()
>>> for line in HTML.split('\n'):
...     print (line)
...     
<div class="sidebar sbt">
 <h4>history</h4>
   <p class="top">
        <strong>First </strong><br>
              Jun 2017
   </p>
   <p class="top">
        <strong>Page </strong><br>
        Last 30 days: <strong>200</strong>        
   </p>
   <p class="top">
        <strong>Last </strong><br>
        2019
    </p>
        </div>
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(HTML, 'lxml')
>>> target = soup.find_all(string=re.compile('Last 30 days'))
>>> target
['\n        Last 30 days: ']
>>> target[0].findParent()
<p class="top">
<strong>Page </strong><br/>
        Last 30 days: <strong>200</strong>
</p>
>>> target[0].findParent().text
'\nPage \n        Last 30 days: 200\n'
```